# How to fix Web Installer "The error code is 2727"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, installation

I've already checked out some of the other posts related to this question, but none seem to help.

Here's the situation: I am create an API and using Web Installer to install. When the program is in a stable state, I am able to build everything and install just fine. However, if I make a change to any file that is (seemingly?) not a .cs file, then the installer has this issue.

Example: I add a service reference to an existing service via the "Add Service Reference" option, the Web.Config is auto-edited, the installer won't install.

Example: I add/edit a seemingly random file, the installer won't install due to Error 2727"

The project builds fine, everything compiles, I don't understand what the problem with the package could be.

The exact text shown is "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2727."

What I've tried:

- Creating a new web installer project
- Adding/Removing file from what the web installer builds (e.g.
  source files from project, debug symbols from project, etc.)

Thank you in advance for anything you might have to offer!

Comment: Please see my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66547161/257470

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is that for the web installer, the only files needed to add are:

- Primary Output from Project
- Content Files from Project

This is working for me now, hopefully this helps whoever comes across this in the future.